# How to extract coordinates {x,y,z} from Raster3D

Tags: graphics3d, image, coordinate-transformation

I want to extract coordinates out of a `Raster3D`. It is possible to extract coordinates out of an `Image3D` by using `PixelValuePositions`. The coordinates extracted are not the coordinates i am looking for because `Image3D` uses a different coordinate system. Is it possible to extract coordinates from `Raster3D`? Or is it possible to translate the coordinates extracted from `Image3D` into the coordinates from `Raster3D`?

Answer (score 5):

`Raster3D` just holds a matrix and an optional data range list, so you can get coordinate postions like this:

```
raster = Raster3D[RandomReal[1, {3, 4, 5}], {{0, 0, 0}, {1,1,1}}];
dim = Dimensions@First@raster;
coordinates = raster[[2]];
p = Position[First@raster, x_ /; x < .1];
pos = Reverse[coordinates[[1]] - Subtract @@ coordinates/dim #] & 
          /@ (p - 1/2);
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.25], raster, PointSize[.05], Red, Point[pos]}]
```

[image]

if your raster doesn't have a coordinate specification use `coordinates={{0,0,0},dim}`

Comment: Note that dim includes the number of channels (i.e. 3 04) as its last element. If you just want the "data range list" if none is provided, you may wish to do a Drop[dim, -1].

Answer (score 4):

You can convert `Raster3D` into `Image3D` simply by applying `Image3D` and then use `ImageValuePositions`:

```
whitePos = {1, 2, 3};
raster = Raster3D[
   ReplacePart[RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5, 3}], whitePos -> {1, 1, 1}]];
i3d = Image3D@raster
```

> [image]

```
xyz = ImageValuePositions[i3d, White]
```

> ```
> {{2.5, 1.5, 0.5}}
> ```

```
PixelValuePositions[i3d, White]
```

> ```
> {{3, 2, 1}}
> ```

As you see from the above, the position returned by `PixelValuePositions` differs from position inside of `Raster3D`. According to the Documentation page for `PixelValuePositions` (the second point under the "Details" section),

> In 3D, `PixelValuePositions[image,val]` returns the positions
>   `{xp,yp,zp}`, such that pixel position `{1,1,1}` corresponds to the
>   center of the bottom-left front pixel.

So the coordinate system used by `PixelValuePositions` is very similar to coordinate system of `Graphics3D`. But for direct use in `Graphics3D` you need `ImageValuePositions` which returns *coordinates* of *centers* of pixels rather than positions. Citing the Documentation page for `ImageValuePositions` (the first point under the "Details" section),

> `ImageValuePositions` assumes the standard image coordinate system.
>
> [image]

So `ImageValuePositions` is what you actually need. For example, you can place a black point inside of the white pixel as follows (warning: unfortunately this code crashes my *Mathematica* 10.4.1 on Windows 7 x64, so I have used version 10.0.1 for evaluating and exporting):

```
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.25], raster}, {Black, PointSize[Large], Point[xyz]}}]
```

> [image]

As [george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079) correctly notices in his [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115771/280), if your `Raster` contains an optional data range list as the second argument, you should take it into account and `Rescale` your `xyz` coordinates accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is i start with an Image3D which i first have to convert to a Raster3D. Is there a solution to extract the same coordinates i would extract using Raster3D out of an Image3D? Or is it possible to convert Image3D to a Raster3D?

Comment: @tom Of course you can use `xyz = ImageValuePositions[Image3D[<...>], White]` right from the start, then convert `Image3D` into `Raster3D` using `Show[Image3D[<...>]][[1]]`.

Comment: When I use ImageValuePositions on an Image3D, I get coordinates which are from the Image3D coordinate system (x,y,z) starting in de left bottom corner. When i plot my coordinates in my ListPointPlot3D, these coordinates are different from my coordinates obtained from a Raster3D. So my Plots won't match.

Comment: @tom Please check the example given at the bottom of my answer: it shows you that coordinates obtained from `Image3D` give exact match with the `Raster3D`: the black `Point` is placed exactly where it should be, i.e. in the center of the white pixel!

Comment: Thank you for helping me! Sadly it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Because the solutions provided didn't work in my case, I tried something different. I extracted coordinates using different software which uses Slices, Rows and Columns as coordinates system (Msrc). I wanted to import this data in mathematica and import my Image3D object as well. When i imported the two, i realised that the coordinates didn't match.The dimensions of images and volumes, however, refer to graphic coordinates x, y, and z and are listed in reverse order.

An array of data is embedded in space like text in a book. The array starts on the top page, top-left corner and continues line by line to the bottom-right corner before it continues on the page below until it ends on the bottom page.

[image: Index coordinates system]

[image: Graphic 3D coordinate system]

In the examples above you can see that not only the coordinate system is different, but also your starting point is different. Index coordinates -> The first voxel is located at the top-left rear corner with coordinate center {1,1,1}.
Graphic 3D coordinate system -> The first voxel is located at the bottom-left front corner with coordinate center {1/2,1/2,(1/2)}.

To adjust my Image3D to a point in which it should have the same starting position i used ImageReflect twice. First Top-> Bottom, Then Front->Back

```
<file=Import["file","Image3D"]>
<file=ImageReflect[file,Top->Bottom]>

<file=ImageReflect[file,Front->Back]>
```

I used PixelValuePositions to extract my coordinates needed

```
<PixelValuePositions[file,1]>
```

Because the vectors in the Msrc coordinate system are different from the xyz coordinate system, I multiplied the coordinates from my list (obtained with pixelValuePositions) by {-1,-1,1}. Slices is pointing in the opposite direction of the Z vector, so -1. Rows is pointing in the opposite direction of Y vector, so -1. Columns is pointing in the same direction of X vector so 1.

Multiplied the coordinates {x,y,z} by {-1,-1,1}

I think there will be an easier solution to the problem. This was the only thing i could come up with.

Comment: Please take time to format your answer properly to facilitate browsing: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help. Also, your answer is not really clear to me. If you provide working code (including sample data) would be the best way to make this answer useful for others.