# Rendering Raster3D intersecting with vector primitives

Tags: bugs, front-end, graphics3d, crash, rendering

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persists through 11.1.1**

**Reported to WRI under [CASE:3678032]**

<sup>It crashes the FrontEnd of *Mathematica* 10.4.1 on Windows</sup>

---

**UPDATE #2 27.04.17 Redacted due to outdated GPU driver on my machine**

---

**UPDATE 27.04.17**
WRI followed up; the issue is not resolved in 11.1.0, but they "see much improved behavior in 11.1.1". Can anybody check this one?
**UPDATE 25.04.17**
I received an e-mail from WRI, they believe the issue has been resolved in 11.1. Can anybody verify this?

---

Consider this simple code:

```
i3d = 1/4 RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5}] // Image3D
```

Now `Show` me this:

```
Show[{i3d, Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Opacity[.6]], Cuboid[{3, 3, 3}]}]}]
```

It takes a lot of time to render and repeatedly freezes and unfreezes MMA.

Note that simply `i3d` returns a very responsive object, renders fast, etc.

I could live with the above. However I need to generate a high-resolution image, like so:

```
Show[{i3d, Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Opacity[.6]], Cuboid[{3, 3, 3}]}]}, ImageSize -> {2400, 1600}]
```

But when I run this line of code, MMA returns an empty box with a tiny little square of the color of `i3d` in the top left corner of the output cell.

I am using version 10.2 on Win7x64 professional. I have 8GB of RAM (I noticed, that MMA consumes several GB when running the first `Show` statement).

Is this a bug? Has it been fixed in a later version?

My eventual desire is to get a hi-res of the following figure:

[image]

The blue cloud is made up of an array of voxels. The yellow triangles in the top half of the image have a setting like `Specularity[White, 10], Opacity[.6]`. When I try to create this figure with `Show[{...}, ImageSize->{900,600}]`, it takes quite a while, but eventually returns a result. When I crank up the `ImageSize` I get a problem similar to the MWE above. When I exclude *either* the cloud *or* the yellow triangles, everything works fine again.

**EDIT** - adding info from the comments:

The problems appear to have become worse through progressive versions of Mathematica.

**V10.0 (Linux):** My colleague managed to generate hi-res images with desired results on our institute's high-performance cluster, although rendering took an abnormally long time.

**V10.1 and V10.2, (Win7x64 professional):** Rendering fails for combinations of `Raster3D`, `Opacity`, and a `Polygon` or `Cuboid` at high resolution, but takes a long time, yet gives a correct result for lower resolutions (`ImageSize`s). For a higher resolution on 10.2 the output cell is generated immediately, but is incorrect:

[image: bug]

Note the few pixels in the top-left of the output cell, which are of the color of the `Raster3D`.

**V10.4:** According to AlexeyPopkov ([link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115791/280)), combining `Raster3D` and `Point` without any mention of `Opacity` now crashes the front-end. This is a different, but seemingly related problem. It does not occur in 10.1 and 10.2. Attempting to render my image in 10.4 on the institute's cluster quickly consumed 0.1 TB of memory without results and froze the front end. At this point we killed the process, but, presumably, it would have led to a crash of the front end.

Comment: Doesn't `Raster3D[]` work?

Comment: @J.M. For my bigger problem I have used various combinations of `Image3D` and/or `Show/Graphics3D@*Raster3D` etc, etc. In the end `Show` always gives a `Graphics3D[{Raster3D[...], Opacity[.6], Cuboid[...]}]` or similar. If you have a concrete working example, please do share. A colleague managed to generate the image on our institute's grid with MMA 10.1. Contrary to this, MMA 10.4 consumed **0.1 TB** of memory on the MWE, before we killed the process.

Comment: I also had a problem rendering `Raster3D` intersecting with `Point` using *Mathematica* 10.4.1 for [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115791/280) answer (the bottom image): it simply crashed the FrontEnd and I was forced to use version 10.0.1 which works fine. Your example also crashes my FrontEnd. Since you can't render also with versions 10.2 and 10.4, I assume the bug was introduced in version 10.2 and become even worse in the latest release. I have added the appropriate tags and the header.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I can render a `Point` inside a `Raster3D` just fine on MMA 10.2. As I can also render a cuboid. The problem arises when I introduce `Opacity[.6]`, and it also happens in 10.1. I think your edit is somewhat inaccurate.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Feel free to rollback my edit. It looks like the problem you describe may be separate from the crashes I experience with version 10.4.1 (but may be not - we can't be sure). In the previous comment you wrote that MMA 10.4.0 takes a lot of memory, so it doesn't crash? So you have a wrong rendering with versions 10.1 and 10.2 and the memory issue with version 10.4.0? Please include this information in the question and also a screenshot(s) the FrontEnd with "an empty box with a tiny little square" instead of the expected output in order to make the question more precise.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov your edit is not completely wrong just not fully accurate, I reckon these problems are related and were in part certainly introduced earlier than 10.1. The memory problem does not mean, that in the end I got a desirable result, as I said, we killed the process. I'll add details a bit later.

Comment: With version 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64 the code `Show[{i3d, Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Opacity[.6]], Cuboid[{3, 3, 3}]}]}]` still crashes the FrontEnd.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks for the feedback. I've asked WRI for clarification.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov please see update

Comment: With version 11.1.1 on the same machine I still get the crash. I don't understand what they mean by "improved" behavior. And [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115791/280) bug is also still here.

Comment: @Alexey well, it seems we have 11.1.1 now available at the institute, so I'll give it a spin today.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With *Mathematica* 10.4.1 on Windows 7 x64 I get FrontEnd crash with your code by default but switching to `"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"` produces the expected output which is relatively responsible (comparing to the `Image3D`):

```
SeedRandom[10]
i3d = 1/4 RandomReal[1, {5, 5, 5}] // Image3D
```

> [image: image3d]

```
Style[Show[{i3d, Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Opacity[.6]], Cuboid[{3, 3, 3}]}]}], 
 RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]
```

> [image: graphics3d]

The option `RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "Software"}` produces the same but seems to be even slower.

An attempt to `Export` this as PNG with `ImageSize -> {2400, 1600}` **crashed my video driver** and I got not responding FrontEnd taking 100% CPU time of one of my cores. So at least my graphical card doesn't allow to render such a large image.

As a workaround you can try to apply an incremental rendering technique. [This post of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19006/280) (see the "EDIT 4" section) shows `Inset`-based approach, another method is suggested by Vitaliy Kaurov (search for "3dImagePartitionExport.nb" in [this](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/509996) Wolfram Community thread).

Comment: Woah. I just added the details. Did you pass the `ImageSize` option to `Export`? What happens if you pass it to `Show`? +1 for the option, I'll toy with that.

Comment: I passed the option via `Show` as in the question. I have just added possible workarounds at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Your workaround (I mean the non-default rendering engine) with hi-res rendering on 10.2 works for me.

Comment: For the record, the cluster managed fine for a `{4800,3200}` resolution in 10.0. I don't know the details of their GPU though.

Comment: And I have just verified, that the non-default engine also works ok for my larger problem, not just the MWE, though it did freeze the notebook for about a minute. I think, this is grounds to accept the answer, pending a future answer that reports a bugfix.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Please report this issue to the tech support with a link to this thread (they may not be informed otherwise).

Comment: Done, updated OP.

Comment: I don't remember if I ever mentioned this explicitly, but my machine does not experience this 'An attempt to Export this as PNG with ImageSize -> {2400, 1600} crashed my video driver...' issue. Export at high-res with non-default engine works fine.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP The critical `ImageSize` strongly depends on hardware (and may be also on drivers). You could try higher value, for example, `ImageSize -> 6000` and check whether it will lead to the crash or not. I'm experiencing this crash for a [long](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Sep/msg00010.html) time.

Comment: Even `Export["Z:\\temp\\test.png", 
 Style[Show[{i3d, 
    Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Opacity[.6]], Cuboid[{3, 3, 3}]}]}, 
   ImageSize -> {6000, 4000}], 
  RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]]` couldn't cause a crash, though the front end froze for a few tense seconds.