# Inset thickness and ImageResolution

Tags: plotting, export

I have noticed that when I export something with an [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) objects,

```
pp[t_] :=  
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, -10, 10},
    Epilog -> 
      {Inset[
         Framed[
           Text[Style[HoldForm["t=" t], 20]], 
           RoundingRadius -> 4, Background -> White], 
         Scaled[{.5, .5}]]}, 
    Frame -> True]
```

When I increase the `ImageResolution`, the border of the inset becomes thicker. Here is what I see:

```
Export["/Users/xx/Desktop/ContC1.png", pp[12], ImageResolution -> 250]
```

[image]

Whereas, if I keep `ImageResolution` lower, the thickness of the inset is more reasonable.

What is happening?

Comment: Probably you use *Mathematica* version lower than 10.4.1 because my tests with versions 10.4.1 and 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64 showed that `ImageResolution` is simply ignored by `Export`. Note that `ImageResolution` (at least in version 10.0 where it works at all) [isn't working as it is supposed to](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64758/280). Which version do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately *Mathematica*'s vector graphics isn't resolution-independent by default and making it resolution-independent it rather tricky and usually doesn't worth the efforts.

I recommend to `Export` the plot as PDF or SVG and then use Adobe Acrobat (or other PDF rendered) or Inkscape  for producing a raster image. This method has many advantages:

- Much more precise rendering of graphical primitives than what *Mathematica's* FrontEnd offers (FrontEnd rounds everything to screen pixels).
- You can specify any resolution you want, and the plot won't change with resolution!
- *Mathematica's* FrontEnd takes a HUGE amount of memory when it renders graphics with high resolution and it's maximum resolution is limited <sup>[[1](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Sep/msg00010.html),[2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121898/280)]</sup>. To the contrary, Adobe Acrobat takes a reasonable amount of memory when saving PDF as PNG image and virtually has no limit on resolution.

And do not stick to rasters, you can `Export` your plot directly into a resolution-independent vector format: PDF, EPS, SVG and EMF are available! Many scientific journals prefer vector formats for figures and any modern desktop publishing software supports a subset of these formats.

Answer (score 0):

Make it image  before exporting.

```
Image@Rasterize@pp@12
```