# Framework behind Graph plots. DynamicNamespace and friends

Tags: graphics, front-end, graphs-and-networks, dynamic

As shown in [DynamicLocation usage](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155157/5478), we can use it to quickly create very nice functionality, that it to refer to graphics' primitives relative coordinates without calculations of boundary etc.

[image]

As shown in the answer for that topic, except of `DynamicLocation` many related things appear:

`DynamicNamespace`, `"DynamicName"`, `TagBox` cell expressions.

What is a big picture and how to use it properly?

Answer (score 23):

*# post under construction but feel free to add anything*

*# undocumented feature*

*# based on observation so it may be wrong*

## TODO:

This post does not cover few things yet, among others:

- how to convert `DynamicLocation` to absolute numeric coordinates. You can use menu item `Evalaution / Convert Dynamic To Literal` on a generated `GraphicsBox` and it will do that, but this packet works only with seleciton, not with expressions/cell expressions. Would be really useful to know this. And it shpuld be possible because Graphs plots usually don't contain DynamicLocation but explicit coordinates.
- does `DynamicLocation` work with `Offset` somehow?

## TL;DR;

- The big picture seems to be a framework for marking boxes with IDs which later can be used to find/replace/modify them (boxes).

  See: [How to set focus of a dialog window?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1454/5478) for an example with `` FrontEnd`BoxReferenceFind ``
- In `Graph/Graphics` world additional tools are available so that marked graphics primitives (`Disk` etc) location can be expressed symbolically, without knowing its numeric values.

  See example from the OP gif:

  ```
  LocatorPane[ Dynamic @ x, Graphics[{
    EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm@None, DynamicName[Rectangle[], "box"]
  , Arrow[{Dynamic[x], DynamicLocation["box", Automatic]}
  ]}]]
  ```

## Symbols guide

- ### `DynamicName`

  `DynamicName[obj_, id_String, type___]` typesets to

  ```
  TagBox[objBoxes, type <> "DynamicName",  BoxID->id]
  ```

  `type` can be `"Private"`, `"Public"` or can be skipped but this additional argument is not supported inside `Graphics`.

  `DynamicName` is a handy way to create "marked boxes" to which we can refer later. This way we can write top level code instead of working with cell expressions.

  Additionaly, usage of `TagBox` makes it fully capable of a round trip to and from boxes:

  ```
  ToBoxes @ DynamicName["A", "test"]
  InputForm @ MakeExpression @ %
  ```

  > ```
  > TagBox["\"A\"", "DynamicName", BoxID -> "test"]
  >
  > HoldComplete[DynamicName["A", "test"]]
  > ```

  `DynamicName` is preferred over explicit e.g. `Rectangle[BoxID -> "id"]` because of that roundtrip ability and because some primitives will not accept options. E.g. `CircleBox` will complain as there are no `CircleBoxOptions` in general, as opposed to `RectangleBoxOptions` `RoundingRadius` etc.
- ### `DynamicNamespace`

  `DynamicNamespace[name_String, expr_, options___]` typesets to `NamespaceBox[name, exprBoxes, opts]`

  Name is optional. Don't know if that argument allows anything fancy yet.

  `DynamicNamespace` helps with modular coding and resolving conflicts for the same DynamicNames. E.g. Withouth the `NamespaceBox` only the first appearance of a specific `BoxID` will be known. See example 1.
- ### `DynamicLocation`

  `DynamicLocation[name_String, spec1_, spec2_]` can be used in graphics primitives as a replacement for point coordinates but pointing to a primitive marked by `BoxID -> name`.

  - `spec1` can be `None` or `Automatic`. `None` will point to the center of the marked primitive.

    Its behavior depends in what primitives we use it, e.g. `Automatic` for `spec1` for line-like (Line,Arrow, etc) will point to the closest point on the edge of marked primitive with respect to parent location. See example 2.
  - `spec2` is ignored when `spec1` is `None` but otherwise can take alignment like specification, `{Left, Top}` etc or `Scaled[t]`.

    `Scaled[t]` can parametrize position on a marked primitive's edge. Can be used for polygon/line-like primitives. See example 3.

## Examples

1. `DynamicNamespace` usage:

   Compare

   ```
   disk[pos_] := {
       DynamicName[Disk[pos], "name"]
     , Arrow[{pos + {2, 2}, DynamicLocation["name", Automatic]}]
   }
       (*compare this *)

   Graphics[ { disk[{0, 0}], disk[{0, -2}], disk[{3, 0}] }, PlotRange -> 5 ]

       (* with this *)

   Graphics[ 
      DynamicNamespace /@ { disk[{0, 0}], disk[{0, -2}], disk[{3, 0}] }
    , PlotRange -> 5 
   ]
   ```

   [image]

   In the first example all `DynamicLocation["name", Automatic]` point to the same, first found, `BoxID -> "name"`. If we combine graphics from different source we can't predict names and `DynamicNamespace` localizes them for us preventing conflics.
2. Context sensitive DynamicLocation:

   ```
   LocatorPane[Dynamic@x, 
    Graphics[{EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm@None, 
      DynamicName[Rectangle[], "box"], 
      Arrow[{Dynamic[x], DynamicLocation["box", Automatic]}]
      ,
      Circle[DynamicLocation["box", Automatic]]
      }, PlotRange -> 2]]
   ```

   As we can see `DynamicLocation["box", Automatic]` means something different for `Circle` and for `Arrow`.
3. Edge parametrization with the third argument of `DynamicLocation`:

   ```
   DynamicModule[{t = 0}, Column[{
     Slider@Dynamic@t, 
     Graphics[{
       EdgeForm@Thick, FaceForm@None, DynamicName[Arrow@CirclePoints[7], "box"]
     , Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, DynamicLocation["box", Automatic, Scaled@Dynamic@t] }]
     }, PlotRange -> 2]
   }]]
   ```

   [image]
4. Usability in `Graphics3D`

   It looks like it is purely 2D feature but it works in `Graphics3D` `Epilog`, which is 2D, together with `3D` primitives!

   ```
   Graphics3D[
       { DynamicName[Cuboid[{-2, -2, 0}], "box"]
       , DynamicName[Cuboid[{1, 1, -2}], "box2"]
       }
     , Epilog -> Dynamic @ {
           Arrow[{Scaled[{0, 0}], DynamicLocation["box", Automatic]}]
         , Arrow[{DynamicLocation["box", Automatic],           DynamicLocation["box2", Automatic] }]
       }
     , PlotRange -> 2
   ]
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Crazy exploration..

Comment: @yode It seems to be around for a long time, would really appreciate such things semi documented in experimental notebooks or something. This is really useful stuff.

Comment: It is first function ``GeneralUtilities`HasDefinitionsQ`` return false but work well as I know.Could you tell me which is your `experimental notebooks`? Actually I have used [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/), but I cannot find anything..

Comment: @yode I just meant 'unofficial documentation' of features that are being used but are not production ready, or something. So that users can learn more but couldn't complain if it breaks ;)

Comment: @Kuba also see `PacletFind["WolframAlphaClient"][[1]]["Location"]` and `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {StyleDefinitions, "WolframAlphaShortInput", 
  NamespaceBoxOptions}]`. The latter defines the `ops` it can take (as the type-set form of `DynamicNamespace` is `NamespaceBox`). The former uses it with a named string arg, etc. They also show how you make that named `DynamicNamespace` do special things (by changing the `Format` of `NamespaceBox`, essentially).

Comment: @b3m2a1 yep, seen it but didn't have time to summarize it properly. Will try to update this post gradualy.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a very useful share for how to use this new feature,such make a smart arrow connect the explanation text with the object,for example

```
Graphics[{DynamicName[Disk[], "disk"], 
  DynamicName[Style[Text["This is a black disk", {3, 2}], 18, Red],"Explanation"], 
  DynamicName[Style[Text["This is a black disk", {0, 2}], 18, Blue],"AnotherExplanation"], 
  Arrow[{DynamicLocation["Explanation", Automatic],DynamicLocation["disk", Automatic]}], 
Arrow[{DynamicLocation["AnotherExplanation",Automatic],DynamicLocation["disk", Automatic]}]}]
```

[image]

You don't need to specify the specific coordinate for your `Arrow`.I think it is useful..