# How can one "shorten" arrows to be drawn between two points but being a bit hemmed in, as not to overlap with the plot markers?

Tags: graphics

The problem arises when you want to connect two point markers in a diagram with an arrow. Just giving the ccordinates of the points to the arrow results in ugliness, as the arrow then overlaps with the point markers:
[image: Two circles, centers connected with an arrow]

whereas one might one to "hem in" the arrow on both ends a bit:

[image: Two circles, arrow stopping short of the circumference]

Comment: From the documentation, "Arrow[{pt1, pt2}, {s1,s2}] sets back s1 from pt1 and s2 from pt2."  Using s instead of {s1, s2} uses the same offset for the arrow head and tail.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the undocumented functions [`DynamicLocation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicLocation) and and [`DynamicName`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicName) to do this (see this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155238/45431) for more details):

```
Graphics[
    {
    Arrowheads[{-Medium,Medium}],
    Arrow[{
        DynamicLocation["ID1", Automatic, Center],
        DynamicLocation["ID2", Automatic, Center]
    }],
    Red,
    DynamicName[Disk[{0,0},.1],"ID1"],
    DynamicName[Disk[{1,1},.2],"ID2"]
    }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is a small utility function that I named `shortenedArrows`

```
Clear[ shortenedArrow];
shortenedArrow[ {p1_, p2_}, {s1_, s2_}] := Module[ {v, a, b},
   v = p2 - p1;
   a = p1 + s1 v;
   b = p1 + (1 - s2) v;
   Return[ Arrow[{a, b}]]
   ];
shortenedArrow[ {p1_, p2_}, s_: 0.05] := 
 shortenedArrow[ {p1, p2}, {s, s}];
```

The function can be used like `Arrow` but accepts an (optional) additional parameter that indicates by what fraction the arrow should be hemmed in. If the optional parameter is a list, it gives the fractional shortening at the beginning and the end of the arrow.

The two graphs above are created via

```
Function[{p1, p2}, 
  Graphics[{Dashed, Red, Disk[#, 0.1] & /@ {p1, p2}, Black, 
    shortenedArrow[{p1, p2}, 0.0] }]][ {0, 0}, {1, 1}]
```

and

```
Function[{p1, p2}, 
  Graphics[{Dashed, Red, Disk[#, 0.1] & /@ {p1, p2}, Black, 
    shortenedArrow[{p1, p2}, 0.1] }]][ {0, 0}, {1, 1}]
```

respectively.